# MultiValueDictKeyError in django 1.11.18

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.7 with Django 1.11.18. I have to connect to an Oracle 11g database and that is why the use of 1.11 version for django.
The below code was working for django 2.0.7 and python 3.7 but when i downgraded my version to 1.11.18 it s started giving me the error.

I am sending a post request via an HTML form. The post request has fields username and password. The python code to retrieve the same is :-

```
username = request.POST[‘username’]
password = request.POST[‘password’]
```

I also tried:-

```
username = request.POST.get(‘username’, False)
```

The above code picks up the default value even though a valid valuse is passed through my form.
Any idea why this is happening and how to solve it.

Edit:- The full part of the code is below

### views.py

```
username = request.POST['username']
password = request.POST['password']
user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
if user is not None:
    login(request)
    request.session['userName'] = username
    return HttpResponse("SUCCESS")
else:
    return HttpResponse("FAILURE")
```

### HTML

```
                    $( "#loginForm" ).submit(function( event ) {

                        // Stop form from submitting normally
                        event.preventDefault();

                        var jqxhr = $.post( "http://127.0.0.1:8000/ScApp2/xxxx/", $( "#loginForm" ).serialize(), function() {
                        })
                            .done(function( data ) {
                                if( data == "SUCCESS")
                                    window.location.href = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/ScApp2/home/xxxx.html';
                                else
                                    alert("Please check your username and password and try again.");
                        })
                            .fail(function() {
                            alert( "ERROR : Please contact the Support Team." );
                        });
                    });
```

### TRACEBACK:-

```
[28/Jan/2019 17:12:24] "POST /xxxx/xxxx/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7
Internal Server Error: /xxxx/xxxx/ScorecardApp20/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\xxxx\xxxx\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 83, in __getitem__
    list_ = super(MultiValueDict, self).__getitem__(key)
KeyError: 'username'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\xxxx\xxxx\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "c:\users\xxxx\xxxx\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
        response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
      File "c:\users\xxxx\xxxx\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
      File "C:\PythonWorkspace\xxxx\xxxx\views.py", line 67, in home
        username = request.POST['username']
      File "c:\users\xxxx\xxxx\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 85, in __getitem__
        raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))
    django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: "'username'"
```

Comment: Share your form and template code, at least. There could be any number of reasons for this, and it's pointless to speculate without seeing some code

Comment: added code.....

Comment: you might have multiple user with same name and password thats why it is returning a queryset and coming error MultiValueDictKeyError

Comment: I have only one user with that name. There is only one superuser in this app.

Comment: @NVS, that is not at all what a MultiValueDictKeyError means.

Comment: @KChow - thanks for the edit, but I was more interested to see the actual Html of the form (not just the JavaScript), and the Form class that you're using. (Unless it's just the default Django login form.)

Comment: I printed request.POST['username'] and its printing the right username passed by the form but still gives this error.

Comment: sorry, I'm confused. Where is the `print` statement? The code and the stacktrace clearly point to the fact that `request.POST` has no `username` key, so it's not possible to `print` it without getting the same error. So either the request is different when you're printing it, or `request.POST` somehow gets altered between the two. Either way, I would still like to see the HTML, as well as to see the full view function (not just the snippet shown above).

Comment: I figured out the issue. The url was not being redirected properly. Thanks for the help.